# FRR Measurement

Tags: oscilloscope, pulse, rise-time

When I try to measure the FRR (time delay in the rising edge of two pulses) between two channels of a GES-2074A GW-Instek digital oscilloscope, it varies depending on the time resolution. First, I thought that the more pulses I add to the screen the FRR was being averaged over the number of pulses being sampled (or displayed on the screen, if they are the same thing). This should mean that by having low enough time resolution it should settle down to a stable value but it keeps increasing.

For reference, I am trying to measure the time difference between two cables of the same length attaching parallel to the same function generator.

Comment: This sounds like an x-y problem. What might be better to ask is how to measure the time difference of two cables.

Comment: That is essentially the task. I thought that by measuring the FRR between two cables coming from a function generator one can measure the time difference between two cables. Do you think there is a problem with this method?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to trigger the 'scope on the first rising edge and let it measure the delay to the second rising edge. Make the time-per-division as small as you can, so that only one rising edge from each signal is displayed. This will allow the 'scope to calculate the delay with the best resolution.

Now, have the 'scope trigger continuously and average the delay measurements **over time**. By letting the scope run for a while you can average many thousands of measurements, while preserving the maximum resolution for each measurement.

Comment: So tried what you suggested. I am using GDS-2074A GW-Instek digital oscillosope (the manual is here (https://www.gwinstek.com/en-global/products/downloadSeriesDownNew/1306/118). The model can be set of Run or Triggered mode by default and I think that what you suggested in your answer. As I increase the timebase (so that many waves fit on the screen) the FRR settles to a stable value which is about a microsecond and I know is too large for the cables used. But if I reduce down to the minimum the mean of the measurements fluctuates (I might be sampling too less values though).